# Django + nginx + gunicorn gives 502 error. very little log information

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I have my server configured like this (this is on a fresh install of ubuntu 10.10)

nginx + gunicorn + django + supervisord to run it

when I try to access my site, I get a 502 error. and this will show up in the error log:

```
2011/06/03 10:40:59 [error] 15066#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: [retracted], server: [retracted], request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:29000/", host: "[retracted]"
```

Here is my nginx.conf
http://pastebin.com/t0V2yFxr

Here is my supervisord.conf
http://pastebin.com/pqVqRLSk

and my gunicorn.conf

```
bind = "127.0.0.1:29000"
logfile = "/sites/[retracted]/logs/gunicorn.log"
workers = 3
```

when I run 
    sudo supervisordctl status

it returns nothing. So this makes me suspect that it is not properly running. However, there is no supervisord.log file (in /var/log/ or in /code/[]/logs/) or gunicorn.log showing errors.

So I cannot debug this at all. Any suggestions on how to get this takin care of?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do debugging if you run supervisord in this way::

```
supervisord --nodaemon --loglevel DEBUG
```

All errors will be dumped to the console.

Also you can try to run debug server on this machine. Maybe your site does not work at all.

Comment: Thanks. For me, the command was: `supervisord --nodaemon --loglevel debug`

Answer (score 0):

If `supervisorctl status` isn't showing anything then it sounds like you didn't run `supervisorctl reload` after updating the configuration.